# Extracting only visible text from SEC 10-k filings (HTML-files)

Tags: r, html-parsing

I have downloaded 10-k filings from the EDGAR System of the SEC using the `edgar` package. For each filing, the underlying html-code is stored in a separate text file. Now, I would like to extract from the html-code only the text visible to the reader of the original html files. This means that I would need to remove all tables, graphics, xbrl and zip documents, etc.

To download the filings:

```
# packages
require(edgar)

# SEC company identifiers (3 companies in this case)
ciK_codes = c(0000099780,0000010456, 0000099780)

# timespan (10 reports per company)
years = c(2011:2020)

# getFilings
getFilings(cik.no = cik_codes, form.type = "10-K", 
                  filing.year = years, 
                  downl.permit = "y", 
                  useragent = "Name Surname E-Mail")
```

So far I have tried to do the following:

```
# packages
require(XML)
require(readr)

# read filing
filing = readr::read_file(path)

# parsing document
doc = XML::htmlParse(filing, asText = TRUE, useInternalNodes = TRUE, addFinalizer = FALSE)

# keeping only text outside of html tags
f.text = XML::xpathSApply(doc, "//text()[not(ancestor::script)][not(ancestor::style)][not(ancestor::noscript)][not(ancestor::form)]",
                           XML::xmlValue)
```

This already works pretty well, but unfortunately the output still contains tables, xbrl documents, etc.